# What does expression -nameserver- mean?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ip, nameserver

If we search for DNS information of a website we find such info:

Nameserver : ns1.any.com

What is it ?

Comment: where are you seeing this - what command are you using ?

Comment: Using any whois service ......

Answer (score 2):

Name servers answer DNS queries. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server):

> A name server (also spelled nameserver) consists of a program or computer server that implements a name-service protocol. It maps a human-recognizable identifier to a system-internal, often numeric, identification or addressing component.
>
> The most prominent types of name servers in operation today are the name servers of the Domain Name System (DNS), one of the two principal name spaces of the Internet. The most important function of these DNS servers is the translation (resolution) of humanly memorable domain names and hostnames into the corresponding numeric Internet Protocol (IP) addresses, the second principal Internet name space which is used to identify and locate computer systems and resources on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

That is the name of the machine that holds the authoritative DNS records for the domain `any.com`.